# Angular: How to display mat cards from left to right only

Tags: html, css, angular

I am building an Angular application that involves in using a lot of card components. Is there a way to show mat cards from left to right ONLY? Right now, new mat cards are placed at the bottom of the existing ones when it runs out of space. How do I make it so that it appends to right of the existing ones? Any help would be appreciated

This is what the HTML file looks like

```
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="chains">
    <mat-card class="example-card">
      <mat-card-header>
        <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
        <mat-card-title>Shiba Inu</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>Dog Breed</mat-card-subtitle>
      </mat-card-header>
      <img mat-card-image src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>
          The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan.
          A small, agile dog that copes very well with mountainous terrain, the Shiba Inu was originally
          bred for hunting.
        </p>
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
        <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>

    <mat-card class="example-card">
      <mat-card-header>
        <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
        <mat-card-title>Shiba Inu</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>Dog Breed</mat-card-subtitle>
      </mat-card-header>
      <img mat-card-image src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>
          The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan.
          A small, agile dog that copes very well with mountainous terrain, the Shiba Inu was originally
          bred for hunting.
        </p>
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
        <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>

    <mat-card class="example-card">
      <mat-card-header>
        <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
        <mat-card-title>Shiba Inu</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>Dog Breed</mat-card-subtitle>
      </mat-card-header>
      <img mat-card-image src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>
          The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan.
          A small, agile dog that copes very well with mountainous terrain, the Shiba Inu was originally
          bred for hunting.
        </p>
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
        <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>

    <mat-card class="example-card">
      <mat-card-header>
        <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
        <mat-card-title>Shiba Inu</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>Dog Breed</mat-card-subtitle>
      </mat-card-header>
      <img mat-card-image src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>
          The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan.
          A small, agile dog that copes very well with mountainous terrain, the Shiba Inu was originally
          bred for hunting.
        </p>
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
        <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>

    <mat-card class="example-card">
      <mat-card-header>
        <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
        <mat-card-title>Shiba Inu</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>Dog Breed</mat-card-subtitle>
      </mat-card-header>
      <img mat-card-image src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>
          The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan.
          A small, agile dog that copes very well with mountainous terrain, the Shiba Inu was originally
          bred for hunting.
        </p>
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
        <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>

    <mat-card class="example-card">
      <mat-card-header>
        <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
        <mat-card-title>Shiba Inu</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>Dog Breed</mat-card-subtitle>
      </mat-card-header>
      <img mat-card-image src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>
          The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan.
          A small, agile dog that copes very well with mountainous terrain, the Shiba Inu was originally
          bred for hunting.
        </p>
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
        <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
  <p>Other Stuff</p>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.page-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.chains {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.chains mat-card {
  display: inline-block;
}

mat-card {
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

What it looks like:
[image: Preview]

Comment: just assign the width of your outer container or tag.

Comment: @AmanSharma thanks for the suggestion. but how does setting the width of the container stops mat cards from populating at the bottom of the existing ones? I want all mat cards to show on the same level, no scrolling up and down, just left to right

Comment: because it allows the extra space for the child tags to free flow to right, and when it takes all space form the parent then it automatically shift to the next line.

Comment: @AmanSharma I tried setting the width to something like 200% and the cards appends to the existing one but the left-to-right scroll doesn't work? I'll update the post and show you what I mean

Comment: give it a property of `overflow:hidden`. and do not update your code here, because it contains `mat` and won't work here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions :) @AmanSharma. I have found a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the parent div overflow, flex to row and specify child width.

```html
<div style="width: 100%; display:flex; flex-direction: row; overflow: auto;">
   <div style="min-width: 300px">
       <mat-card class="example-card"></mat-card>
   </div>
   <div style="min-width: 300px">
       <mat-card class="example-card"></mat-card>
   </div>
   <div style="min-width: 300px">
       <mat-card class="example-card"></mat-card>
   </div>
   <div style="min-width: 300px">
       <mat-card class="example-card"></mat-card>
   </div>
   ...
</div>
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmra3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcard-fancy-example.html